# why does brasero think the windows 10 iso is bigger than it actually is?

Tags: linux, debian, dvd-burning

Its 4.6GB, but it thinks its 4.9GB. why does it thinks its 4.9GB

[image]

Comment: This is the age old 1000 vs 1024 kilo byte issue: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&q=4.6+gibibyte+to+gigabyte Basically it is metric base 10 "manufacturer megabytes" (which would show larger) vs the 2^10=1024 "computer megabytes".

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the actual version of Windows, but Microsoft recommends 8 GB on a USB key
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10

I use a 32 GB  USB for making Windows 10 Systems.

Comment: This completely fails to answer the actual question that was asked.

Comment: Files don't just "expand a bit" on their own. If they do it is because they are compressed and you actively had to do something to make it expand or something is being added. A 4.6GiB file does not miraculously expand to be larger. The actual answer is as per my comment on the question and in the duplicates: that one tool is using a different definition for kilobytes to the other.

Comment: The "size on disk" isn't larger either and it has nothing to do with the "arrangement of data". Sure there is some extra file overhead which says "this file is over there" but it does not mean that a 4.6GiB file balloons out to 4.9. It is *literally* just the way that sizes are measured being different. It's that hard drive and storage media manufacturers decided to use "metric" 1000-byte notation for kilobytes while everyone in the computer world knew it as 1024-bytes. There is the exact same amount of data, but it is measured differently. No expansion, no rearrangement, just measurement.

Comment: It is the same thing as imperial vs metric measurement and the fact that [American gallons are different from actual imperial gallons](https://www.google.com/search?q=american+gallon+vs+imperial+gallon). They all measure the same thing and you have exactly the same amount of stuff, but they give different numbers showing how much stuff there is.

Comment: Fine. Use a bigger media, but at the very least you should **know** and be able to explain **why**. This site is about *teaching* people how to solve their problems as much as it is solving them, and just saying "oh I use a bigger stick because, oh I don't know... *shrug*" doesn't help them or you. It is lazy, unhelpful and doesn't actually tell anyone anything about the actual problem at hand. Your answers should be written so that if someone came here with another similar but slightly different problem in the future then it could conceivably help them too.

Comment: This answer absolutely fails to answer the author’s question.